# Add text fields between checkboxes on a node form

Tags: 7, forms

How do I add text fields between checkboxes in a List on a node edit form ?

Looks like this:

[image]

How do I do it with form_alter ? Or other methods?

Comment: is it a  node edit form ??

Comment: @ShreyaShetty Yes

Comment: you only have two item in your check boxes list?

Comment: @zhilevan these two fields are between three other fields ie 2nd and 3rd item

Comment: @pNg you mean you have two text field  and one select checkboxes , and what to  render  text fields betweeen  check boxes? 
is number of  select options determined( I mean number of check boxes)?

Comment: @zhilevan I have added an image of the entire list of checkboxes in the post. Yes I want to render text fields between check boxes. And the number of select options are determined i.e. 5 options.